# Config variable not being fetched as expected from application.yml

Tags: grails-3.1

I have config variable(in application.yml) as:

```
xyz:
exception.emails: ['abc@gmail.com']
```

While fetching this in local works fine but after deploying war I am getting config variable as:

```
xyz: [
    exception: [
        emails[
            0
        ]: abc@gmail.com
    ]
]
```

I am pulling this as:

```
def email = Holders.config.grails.xyz.exception.emails
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm actually surprised this work at all, because I don't think that is proper yml syntax looking at the default application.yml they specify a list of userAgents like this:

```
grails:
    mime:
        disable:
            accept:
                header:
                    userAgents:
                        - Gecko
                        - WebKit
                        - Presto
                        - Trident
```

Personally I like to use an application.groovy and use groovy syntax like this:

```
grails {
    mime {
        disable {
            accept {
                header {
                    userAgents:
                    ['Gecko', 'WebKit', 'Presto', 'Trident']
                }
            }
        }
```

It maybe a little out of date but here is an example of a application.yml converted to application.groovy:
https://github.com/virtualdogbert/Grails3Tutorial/blob/step_01_settings_yml_to_groovy/grails-app/conf/application.groovy

Also note in the past you could run code from application.groovy, however if you have any imports they won't work,because application.yml/groovy, is meant for the cli(pre runtime), so as a workaround you can also specify a runtime.groovy, where you can have imports. If you ever go the extra mile and write a plugin, you can specify a plugin.groovy, to set defaults.